# What does "rosy" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I can't understand the meaning of this sentence:

> This is a sad sight for Mediators’ friends, who will come to depend on their rosy outlook.

The complete paragraph is:

> Unlike their Extraverted cousins though, Mediators will focus their
>   attention on just a few people, a single worthy cause – spread too
>   thinly, they’ll run out of energy, and even become dejected and
>   overwhelmed by all the bad in the world that they can’t fix. This is a
>   sad sight for Mediators’ friends, who will come to depend on their
>   rosy outlook.

Comment: Did you try looking up 'rosy' in a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Rosy" in this context means *characterized by or tending to promote optimism*. This can be found in the dictionary.

A "rosy outlook" therefore is an *optimistic view of the future*.

Sometimes the expression a "rosy outlook" is used sincerely but is often used *sarcastically*, especially when describing someone else's outlook with an implication that they are *ill-informed* or *overly-optimistic*.

The meaning of your paragraph is that "mediators" are a type of person who like to help people. They have a rosy, or *positive* outlook - they believe that problems can be solved. As such, the friends of "mediators" come to depend on that positivity. The paragraph suggests that mediators can sometimes run out of energy from trying to hard to help others, and when their efforts fail they can become *negative* and dejected, which has an effect on those friends who rely on their normal positivity.

Comment: Can you rewrite that sentence in a simpler form?

Comment: Not really sure how *A "rosy outlook" therefore is an optimistic view of the future* can be rewritten in a simpler form.